# How do I return a single or multiple results from the same graphQL query?

Tags: graphql

I have set up a `GraphQL` endpoint that returns me a `client`

```
query {
    client(id:1) {
      clientId
    }
}
```

and another that returns a list of `clients`

```
query {
    clients {
      clientId
    }
}
```

I have 2 backing db queries for these 2 `graphql` queries, but is there a way to have a single `query` for both?  Or what is the `graphql` way of handling this?

Answer (score 4):

The GraphQL way of handling this is exactly how you have done it. You usually need separate fields in your schema to handle retrieving one item vs multiple, just like you would have separate endpoints for these in a REST API.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single end point that returns a `GraphQLList` Type. This list can contain either one object or however many.

In your case, that single end point will be `clients`. You just have to use your backend to see if the consumer of your GraphQL API has supplied any arguments i.e. `clientId`. If the `clientId` has been supplied, filter your `clientRepo` by that supplied `clientId`. Otherwise return the whole list (repo) of `clients`.

```
clients: {
  type: new GraphQLList(clientType), <--- Note this is a GraphQLList type
  args: {
    id: {
      type: GraphQLInt
    },
  },
  resolve: (parent, args) => {
    if (args.id) {
      return clientRepo.find(args.id);
    }
    return clientRepo.findAll();
  }
}
```

---

You might want to visit the following links:

https://jaketrent.com/post/return-array-graphql/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52773152/4195803